# Optimize query of mysql

Tags: mysql

In current scenario, My Database store each user order item, Where one order have multiple items and all items will have same orderNumber. I am not much experienced in mysql. But I had modified the default search query to get the order by auditTimestamp. As user can edit order items, Which will update the single product auditTimestamp.

I have created an inner query earlier to iterate all orders and then group by them, After that get their latest auditTimestamp using MAX function. Currently I need to optimize it. below is the sample. Where I need to optimize the inner join.

```
select
   distinct ORDER.ORDERID
           ,ORDER.ORDERNUMBER
           ,ORDER.CREATIONDATE
           ,ORDER.STATUS  
           ,ORDER.AUDITTIMESTAMP
           ,ORDER.USERID
           ,ORDER.SEQ
           ,maxaudit.maxaudittimestamp as maxaudittimestamp
  from
   ORDER  as ORD
   INNER JOIN (select
               ORDER.ORDERID
                ,ORDER.ORDERNUMBER
                ,ORDER.CREATIONDATE
                ,ORDER.STATUS  
                ,ORDER.AUDITTIMESTAMP
               ,ORDER.USERID
               ,ORDER.SEQ
               ,MAX(ORD1.AUDITTIMESTAMP) maxaudittimestamp
               from
                ORDER ORD1
               where
                ORD1.USERID = 1 AND
                ORD1.STATUS IN ('Active'
                                     ,'CANCELLED'
                                     ,'OUT FOR DELIVERY'
                                     ,'Void')
               GROUP BY
                ORD1.ORDERNUMBER) maxaudit
     on maxaudit.ORDERID = ORD.ORDERID
  WHERE
   WAR.ORDERID = 1) ORRDATA
   WHERE 1 = 1 AND
 ,ORDER.SEQ = 1
ORDER BY
 ORRDATA.maxaudittimestamp DESC;
```

As Result I need to get All orde by user and sort them by latest first. But whose primary order of seq = 1, status should be 'Active'
                                     ,'CANCELLED'
                                     ,'OUT FOR DELIVERY'
                                     ,'Void'

Optimisation required to replace

Comment: Wondering how this can be working as "ORDER" is a reserved word and  you don't quote it

Comment: Make your live easier . Dont use reseverd keyword for schemas and fieldnames

Comment: @B001ᛦ real query is working fine, this is just an dummy example. The real object is to optimise the inner query with inner join, When I try to use inner join, so while writting group by it gives error. So am stuck .